# Angular rxjs how to trigger again on reload a shared observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

[Angular: 14.0.1, rxjs: 7.5.0]

So I got an observable like `user$ = http.get('/user')` that I share in ngOnInit with `.pipe(shareReplay())` so that it won't be called unnecessary especially when using and async pipe `{{(user$ | async)?.name}}` for example.

And after modifying the user with a http PUT request I want to load the user to display its new values. To do so I use a reload Subject that I trigger in the result of the PUT request

```
this.put('/user').subscribe(() => this.myService.sendReload()):
```

And I listen to the reloadRequest to subcribe to `user$`

```
this.myService.reload().pipe(
switchMap(() => this.user$)
).subscribe();
```

However, as I define `user$` as shared, the reload pipe subscribe only returns the previous value and doesn't fetch a new value with an http GET request

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to create a new reference to `this.user$` through calling `http.get` again so that it refetches.

Comment: I did something like that at first though I pass `this.user$` as an Input parameter to a child component. And the issue was that subscribing to `user$` in the child component would not be getting the new value that i fetch in the parent component with   my switchMap

Comment: You should look into using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `shareReplay`. Seems like the appropriate use case

Comment: Except I use openapi generator to create my http services to communicate with my backend (based on my swagger yaml file) and all my service methods returns are Observable. So I'm stuck with Observables

Comment: What if you try something like `this.user$ = merge(of(true), this.myService.reload()).pipe(
switchMap(() => http.get('/user'))
)`  (and add in your shared replay by `pipe` as you need

Answer (score 1):

You can design the `user$` observable to begin with the `reload()` trigger observable/subject:

```js
private loadUser$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);

user$ = this.loadUser$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.http.get('/user')),
    shareReplay()
);

updateUser(): void {
    this.put('/user').subscribe(
        () => this.reloadUser()
    );
}

reloadUser(): void {
    this.loadUser$.next();
}
```

Comment: looks a lot like I got with exhaustMap instead of switchMap